# Route depending on a session value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Is it possible to route a request depending on a session value?

I would like to route `/test` to `test#withoutsession` or `/test` to `test#withsession` depending on a session value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably applying dynamic constraints to your routes, like this:

```
get '/test', :to => 'test#withoutsession', :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:user_id].blank? }
get '/test', :to => 'test#withsession', :constraints => lambda{ |req| req.session[:user_id].present? }
```

Reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints